# How to POST two Dynamic elements using oneJquery

Tags: jquery

I can post one value of StatusAll element, but don't know how to add the value of Ctrl_no element in the same query. I did not add the code for Ctrl_no to the script, no clue. Both elements are dynamic.

```
        $(document).ready(function() {

    $('input[id^="stag"]').on('click', function() { 

            var $buttonData = this.value;
               $.post('https://172.16.101.120/servlet/AppQueOpenPDF',{FormName:$buttonData},function(data) {   

        $('#RepResponse3').html(data);

                });

            });

        });          

    </script>

<table>

          <TR>
            <TD>
              <input type='button' id='stag<%=count++%>' name='StatusAll' value='HIST62083'>
            </TD>
            <TD>
              <input type='hidden' id='ctag<%=count++%>'' name='Ctrl_No' value='34231'>
            </TD>
          <TR>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your post request parameters to add another variable. The second parameter can be a map and can be used to send multiple key:value pairs.

```
var secondData = $("input[name=Ctrl_No]").val(); //Get the value by Name
$.post('https://172.16.101.120/servlet/AppQueOpenPDF', {FormName:$buttonData, Ctrl_no:secondData}, function(data) {   
     $('#RepResponse3').html(data);

 });
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. I spent 4 hours trying to figure. thanks again

Comment: I see one problem your element all  ways gives me the first element even though I click on forth or any other element. can I use Id as it has unique counter don't know the syntax?

Comment: @ChinoKhan How many elements do you have ?? Does all the elements have same name?? Can you post the full code?

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like the following which will grab all your form/table/whatever elements and send them..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').on('click', function() {
        $.post("https://172.16.101.120/servlet/AppQueOpenPDF", $('table :input').serialize(), function(data) {
            $('#RepResponse3').html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xr0g58rL/